# How to setup a listener for clickable element in a ListBox

Tags: android, android-listview

I have an Activity (not a ListActivity, although I should probably convert my code into one since it's only displaying a ListView). In this ListView I have a setup a layout for the rows, and it contains two TextView and one CheckBox. The Layout is shared by another Activity, so I have set `CheckBox.visibility="GONE"` so the activities can enable them on their own if they need the checkboxes.

I have a SimpleCursorAdapter for my ListView. In this adapter I override `setViewValue()` so I can enable the checkbox, like this:

```
adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.location_browser_listview_relative, cursor, FROM, TO);
adapter.setViewBinder(new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() {
  @Override
  public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {
    if (view.getId() == R.id.checkBox) {
      // Enable the star-checkbox
      ldb.isFavourite(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(LocationDB.C_ID)));
      view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      ((TextView)view).setText("");
      return true;
    }

    return false;
  } // setViewValue
}); // setViewBinder
```

furthermore I have setup an `onClickListener()` because the user is supposed to click a list element (a whole row). The listener goes like this:

```
listItems.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
    final int numItems = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(LocationDB.C_NUM_ITEMS));
    String foo = String.format(TAG + "Clicked: %d", numItems);
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, foo);

    AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(StoreBrowser.this);
    dialog.setMessage("Vill du bevaka?");
    dialog.setPositiveButton("Ja", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // TODO: Save to DB here
        System.out.println("Hello from onClick");

        ldb.addFavourite(ID);
      }
    }); // setPositiveButton         

    dialog.setNegativeButton("Nej", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked no", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
    }); // setNegativeButton         

    dialog.show();
  } // onItemClick
}); // setOnItemClickListener
```

Questions:

1. In setViewValue(), the code `ldb.isFavourite()` is issued *three times* according to Logcat (I use Log.d() in the method). Why is it called three times? There's a SQL-query running in it, and I suspect it will be quite expensive running it three times for each listview row.

2a. How can I intercept a click on the checkbox? I need to toggle a boolean variable when the user toggles the checkbox. The `onClick()` only fires when the user clicks the whole listview row, but when the checkbox is clicked nothing happens.

2b. Is there a way to collect all checkbox info at the same time instead of toggling a boolean when user clicks? I mean, when the user is done selecting, is there a way to go through all the listelements one by one in a loop and fetch the click-value?

Bonus question: I suspect I should rewrite this code and manually inflate the listview and its elements, so if anyone can point me to a good resource describing this kind of work I'd be grateful. Google's API-docs aren't very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ 1. How many rows does your cursor iterate over? - I suspect it might be 3.

@ 2b. Not quite sure about the `ListView`, but have a look at [`ViewGroup.getChildAt()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#getChildAt%28int%29) to iterate through the `ListView`'s children and at [`View.findViewById()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#findViewById%28int%29) to locate your desired child view inside each child of the ListView.

Comment: @1: There is currently only one row in the DB and only one ListView-row, that's why I'm beign puzzled as of why the method is called three times.